# How to prevent adding duplicate items in a text box using Jquery autoSuggest

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using Jquery autoSuggest to add multiple items in a text box . I want to prevent adding same items twice. Is there any way to do this

My autoSuggest code is like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

"use strict";
$("input#Cidtextbox").autoSuggest("index.php?r=ajax/test&pid=<?=$project->id;?>",
    {
    preFill: <?=$list->getObj(); ?>,
    minChars: 2,
    matchCase: false,
    selectedItemProp: 'name',
    selectedValuesProp: 'value',
    searchObjProps: 'name,email',
    asHtmlID: "listusers",
    });

});
```

any way to do this Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What is the output that you are getting using ajax? Can you show us that?

Comment: also provide a link to that plugin's docs. not everyone has heard of it

Comment: I getting out put as [{"value":"137","name":"test test | testcompany"}]  and I want to prevent showing this values again on list when user try to add same

Comment: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin